# React deployed on Tomcat to IST, UAT and Prod

Tags: reactjs, deployment

we are developing a react app on node server and staring it with npm start but for IST, UAT, and prod we thought of deploying it through gradle spring boot application on tomcat.

For this did npm run build which created build structure, copied and pasted that build structure under webroot and started the boot app its working fine.

My doubt is how to deploy this spring boot app in different environments IST, UAT, and Prod because based on environment my URL in fetch should change.

Please let me know the way to do this.

Thank you..

Comment: if you're generating a war file to deploy then in your gradle build you can specify where to look for your index.html that has bundle.js connected to it. Connect npm build folder to gradle ''project.webAppDirName=npm build folder". I'm also using com.moowork.node plugin to execute npm build so that i can create a deploy-able file with one command.

Comment: Am able to deploy my react app in tomcat but how to specify environment, based on environment my URL in fetch method will change..

Comment: If you're talking about the fetch URL in React app, then you should use Webpack.DefinePlugin and define API_URL based on the development mode. I currently have three webpack config file, one for common config, one for dev, one for prod (more - https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/). I define API_URL as a global variable in webpack which I am able to use anywhere in the React app. The API_URL changes based on development mode. npm run build-prod, npm run build-dev, you can create two separate npm scripts that uses different webpack config files to build. I hope this what you are looking for

Comment: npm run build-ist, this I will execute on the node and will get build folder that folder I will copy in webroot it works.. to deploy to uat I can't use same build folder, again I need to run the command npm run build-uat in node and generate build and need to copy in webroot is this the way..